# Função que cria lista dentro de lista

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, algoritmo

```
def add_divisors(list_num):
    final_list = []
    divisors = []
    for number in list_num:
        for x in range(1, number+1):
            if number % x == 0:
                divisors.append(x)
                final_list.extend(divisors.copy())
                divisors.clear()
    return final_list
        
    
print(add_divisors([3, 4, 6]))
```

Basicamente esse programa imprime:

```
[1, 3, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 3, 6]
```

Eu gostaria de colocar os divisores de cada número dentro de uma lista separada para cada um, exemplo:

```
[[1, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3, 6]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Internamente precisa criar as listas internas, então em cada passo você cria uma lista diferente, portanto inicializa a lista vazia e no final do laço interno adiciona essa lista para a lista externa. è muito simples, a lista interna deve se comportar igual, não tem porque fazer diferente. A ú nica diferença é que na internet deve adicional algo apenas condicionalmente, mas o resto a estrutura é idêntica, ou seja, para fazer a mesma operação você executa a mesma operação.

O código atual é confuso e faz coisas que não deveriam.

```
def add_divisors(list_num):
    final_list = []
    for number in list_num:
        divisors = []
        for x in range(1, number + 1):
            if number % x == 0:
                divisors.append(x)
        final_list.append(divisors)
    return final_list

print(add_divisors([3, 4, 6]))
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/lAH5yF). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/edfjnftn-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/ResetAccumulator.py).

Answer (score 4):

Você pode realizar essa tarefa de usando uma [compreensão de lista](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). A documentação define assim:

> Compreensões de lista fornece uma maneira concisa de criar uma lista.
> Aplicações comuns são criar novas listas onde cada elemento é o
> resultado de alguma operação aplicada a cada elemento de outra
> sequência ou iterável, ou criar uma subsequência de elementos que
> satisfaçam uma certa condição.

E nesse caso é possível aplicar uma compreensão de lista onde cada elemento sublista do `resultado` será formada apenas pelos divisores de `n` que é um número contido na entrada `list_num`.

```
def add_divisors(list_num):
    resultado = []
    for n in list_num:
        resultado.append([x for x in range(1, n+1) if n % x == 0])
    return resultado
```

Exemplo:

```
>>> print(add_divisors([3, 4, 6]))
[[1, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3, 6]]
```

Ainda é possível conseguir uma produção mais compacta aninhando compreensões de lista:

```
def add_divisors2(list_num):
    return [[x for x in range(1, n+1) if n % x == 0] for n in list_num]
```

Exemplo:

```
>>>print(add_divisors2([3, 6, 8]))
[[1, 3], [1, 2, 3, 6], [1, 2, 4, 8]]
```